# Installing chrome-gnome-shell for Firefox snap

Tags: firefox, snap, 18.04, gnome-shell

After a fresh install of 18.04, I've installed [the Firefox snap](https://snapcraft.io/firefox) rather than the APT package.

Now I'm trying to tweak GNOME extensions at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, and it's showing me:

[image: GNOME extensions error]

This is because of the way snaps are sandboxed, it doesn't have access to the system version of `chrome-gnome-shell`. I assume it's a similar problem to those in these threads:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/chrome-gnome-shell-does-not-work-with-chromium-snap/3377
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/package-gnome-extension-together-with-snap-app/2892

Does anyone know if there's a solution to getting `chrome-gnome-shell` to work with the Firefox snap?

---

I found the same question has already been asked [on the snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-snap-is-unable-to-access-chrome-gnome-shell-connector/4562), but there's no answer there yet either.

Comment: Not a solution to the problem in hand, but you can manually install GNOME extensions.